# What is the best way to achieve token based authorization using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working with Spring 4 and am using Spring security and my goal is to have token based authorization with tokens granted upon successful login. I've done a lot of research and different people do different things. Some people create filters and their own token classes, and basically do a lot of heavy lifting. During my research I stumbled upon remember me in Spring, and I was easily able to implement what I wanted. Is this the best approach? Does Spring really do everything for you?

Answer (score 1):

Check [Spring Security OAuth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/). Navigate through examples. Also read [OAuth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). It is difficult use any OAuth library without understanding the spec.

Comment: So what am I getting with just Spring Security no oauth? There are plans to implement oauth for the api, but for now we just want basic security and from what I read Spring Security should handle this? Basically what I want is login page to be exposed, but all other pages to be blocked unless user is logged in. Oauth seems a bit overkill for this

Comment: Then, you are looking at Form based authentication which Spring Security provides by default. Yes Spring Security OAuth is not for you. You can achieve it with Spring Security with minimal configuration but it can not do everything for you. You have to configure it according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring OAuth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) will give you various types of authentication mechanisms.